# Reading a file from the SD card

Tags: android, file, directory, sd-card

I have placed the file "ecg.text" into the directory mnt/sdcard/ecg/ecg.text and am then using the following code to read it but keep getting the catch (FileNotFoundException). Any help or suggestions on how to locate the file would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

the Main activity class:

```
ECGFilereader reader;

    try {
        reader = new ECGFilereader("ecg");
        reader.ReadFile(waves);

        for (int chan=0; chan<ECGFilereader.numChannels; chan++) {
            waves[chan].drawSignal(c, (wavePos[chan])); //new Waveform may need to be created
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the ECGFilereader.java

```
public class ECGFilereader {  

public final static int numChannels = 12;   // the data is stored in 12 channels, one for each lead
public final static int numSamples = 500*6; //500 = fs so *6 for 6 seconds of data
public File file;
private Scanner scanner;
short [] [] ecg = new short [numChannels] [numSamples];

 public ECGFilereader (String fname) throws FileNotFoundException 
 {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();       //accesses the ecg file from the SD card
    file = new File(dir, "mnt/sdcard/ecg/ecg.text");
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
}
public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) // sorts data into and array of an array (12 channels each containing 5000 samples)
{
    for (int m=0; m<numSamples && scanner.hasNextInt(); m++)
    {
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int chan = 0; chan<numChannels && scanner.hasNextInt(); chan++)
        {
            ecg [chan] [m] = (short) scanner.nextInt();     
        }
    }

    for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
        waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]); // sets a signl equal to the ecg array of channels
    return true;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.
I believe it is:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: also, in public ECGFilereader, dir has the value of "/mnt/sdcard/" already, so you do not need to specify it again when you're assigning the value of file

Comment: OK thanks, how do I need to put that into the manifest because I have tried just pasting that ^ and also have tried having <permission ... </permission> but it has appeared to make no difference.

Comment: in public ECGFilereader, make sure to make file = new file (dir, "/ecg/ecg.text");

Comment: the other thing I could recommend trying is: File dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath + "/ecg") and file = new File (dir, "ecg.text")

Comment: Also, sorry if this is redundant but are you sure the file extension is .text and not .txt?

Comment: No that hasn't worked either but thanks again for your help, and yes it is .txt but in my desperation to make it work have also been trying .text each time :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `file = new File(dir, "ecg/ecg.text");` ?

However, I can't see why you would get `FileNotFoundException` when you have not even read the file from the disk (you have just created a new File object). Is there some code that you forgot to upload?

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: I do agree with you that the FileNotFoundException is odd as it fails when I'm debuggin it on the line that reads 'reader = new ECGFilereader("ecg");' but that is all of the code that it should go to.